# Python tqdm TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp, tqdm

I tried to create a progress bar to view progress of file transferring by using the below code.

```python
from tqdm import tqdm
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
srv = pysftp.Connection(host=host,username=username,password=password,cnopts=cnopts)
with tqdm(unit = 'blocks', unit_scale = True, leave = False, miniters = 1, desc = 'Uploading......', total = filesize) as tqdm_instance:
    srv.put("D:\\wp-deploy.jpg","/var/www/html/wp-deploy.jpg",callback=lambda sent:tqdm_instance.update(len(sent)))
```

and I got this error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: It appears that the callback for the `srv` object is passed two parameters, but your callback only accepts one. Have you read the documentation for to see the requirements for the callback? That's literally what the error is telling you: your lambda takes one arguments but it is being given two.

Comment: I figured out the error. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put):

> - **callback** (*callable*) – optional callback function (form: `func(int, int)`) that accepts the bytes transferred so far and the total bytes to be transferred

Comment: I fixed by adding `lambda sent,total: tqdm_instance.update(sent)` to the callback